# Will I be let into the US if I request a passport from a country in the Trump travel ban?

Tags: united-states, international, air-travel

I currently hold a permanent resident status in the US and planned on traveling internationally in next couple of months. Since I need a visa to enter to the country I am traveling to, I would have to request my passport from my country (listed in the travel ban.) I am NOT traveling to my country but rather using my passport from my country as an entry to another country (since I don't hold a US passport yet).

Will this effect my permanent resident status in the US?

Comment: You will generally need a passport from your country of citizenship to travel anywhere, whether you need a visa or not.  Few countries will admit you without a passport (Canada is the only one I know, and even then I think you need a passport if you are flying there).

Comment: What of 1951 Convention travel documents?

Comment: @user6276 Noah does not appear to qualify for such a document.  I meant "you" personally, not in its impersonal sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newly-reinstated [presidential proclamation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/presidential-proclamation-enhancing-vetting-capabilities-processes-detecting-attempted-entry-united-states-terrorists-public-safety-threats/) says (Sec 3(b)) says

> The suspension of entry pursuant to section 2 of this proclamation
>   shall not apply to:
>
> (i) any lawful permanent resident of the United States;

The [State department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/important-announcement.html) also lists exceptions to the travel ban on 8 countries, identifying those who "will not be subject to any travel restrictions listed in the Proclamation"

> d)     Any lawful permanent resident (LPR) of the United States;

Requesting / receiving a passport (or renewed passport) from your current country of citizenship does not invalidate your permanent resident status. Additionally, State says

> No visas will be revoked pursuant to the Proclamation.  Individuals
>   subject to the Proclamation who possess a valid visa or valid travel
>   document generally will be permitted to travel to the United States,
>   irrespective of when the visa was issued.

If you stay out of the country too long, that could cause a problem. If you plan to stay away more than a year, you have to first apply for a [reentry permit](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-131instr.pdf).

This is the current state of the law, which is subject to change.

Comment: As noted in the application form you link to, there are alternatives to the reentry permit.

Comment: So I may use my foreign passport to enter another country and use my permanent resident card to re-entry the US?

Comment: @Noah, not only *may* you do that, you basically *must* do it.  It's the normal way for LPR's, even without the travel ban complication.

Comment: @Noah: "So I may use my foreign passport to enter another country and use my permanent resident card to re-entry the US?" Normally, as a permanent resident, you would show both your passport and green card when boarding the airplane and when you go through US immigration. The ban does not apply to permanent residents and there is no reason you should be shy about showing your passport. Technically, a US permanent resident with a green card is not required to have a passport to travel to or enter the US, but not showing a passport is likely to invite more confusion and questions.